# Two variables are not recognized as identical by assert

Tags: types, sum, stata

I would like to know more about the behavior of the following code:

```
clear
set obs 10000
set seed 98034

* I generate three variables
generate double u1 = runiform()
generate double u2=u1

*check
assert u2==u1
***

generate double var1=runiform()

* I generate some ids
generate byte id_=0

forvalues i=1(1)`=10000/100'{
    replace id_=`i' if _n>`=(`i'-1)*`=10000/100''
}

*I sum by id_ u1 and u2
bysort id_: egen double u11= total(u1)
bysort id_: egen double u21= total(u2)

*check
assert u11==u21
***

*I drop duplicates
bysort id_: drop if _n>1

*I generate a new variable which should be equal to var1 (I am adding and 
*subtracting the same quantities)

generate double var2= var1 - u11 + u21

*(1) 
assert var2==var1
```

In particular, I cannot understand why `assert` (1) fails, I have generated every variable I have summed in the same way so `var1` and `var2` should be identical.

Interestingly, if I order differently the sum, `assert` works:

```
drop var2
generate double var2= - u11 + u21 + var1 

*(2)
assert var2==var1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two variables are not identical. To see this, change their `format`:

```
format var1 %20.15f
format var2 %20.15f

list var1 var2 in 1/10

     +---------------------------------------+
     |              var1                var2 |
     |---------------------------------------|
  1. | 0.498376312204773   0.498376312204776 |
  2. | 0.394671386281136   0.394671386281132 |
  3. | 0.515152901323075   0.515152901323077 |
  4. | 0.789668809822002   0.789668809822004 |
  5. | 0.931897887273974   0.931897887273976 |
     |---------------------------------------|
  6. | 0.947614996238336   0.947614996238336 |
  7. | 0.207296218919878   0.207296218919879 |
  8. | 0.368812285027951   0.368812285027950 |
  9. | 0.565084085641873   0.565084085641871 |
 10. | 0.331114583239097   0.331114583239099 |
     +---------------------------------------+
```

The [ordering of mathematical operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) does matter and takes place from left to right:

```
generate double var2= var1 - u11 + u21
format var2 %20.15f

generate double v2a = - u11 + u21
generate double v2b = var1 + v2a
format v2b %20.15f

generate double v2c = var1 - u11
generate double v2d = v2c + u21
format v2d %20.15f

list var2 v2b v2d in 1/10

     +-----------------------------------------------------------+
     |              var2                 v2b                 v2d |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 0.498376312204776   0.498376312204773   0.498376312204776 |
  2. | 0.394671386281132   0.394671386281136   0.394671386281132 |
  3. | 0.515152901323077   0.515152901323075   0.515152901323077 |
  4. | 0.789668809822004   0.789668809822002   0.789668809822004 |
  5. | 0.931897887273976   0.931897887273974   0.931897887273976 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------|
  6. | 0.947614996238336   0.947614996238336   0.947614996238336 |
  7. | 0.207296218919879   0.207296218919878   0.207296218919879 |
  8. | 0.368812285027950   0.368812285027951   0.368812285027950 |
  9. | 0.565084085641871   0.565084085641873   0.565084085641871 |
 10. | 0.331114583239099   0.331114583239097   0.331114583239099 |
     +-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

In this case there is also likely a precision issue involved because of the magnitude of the differences. For further details type `help precision` in Stata's prompt.